# How to restrict movement of a Pygame character?

Tags: python, oop, pygame, game-development

I'm building a game in Pygame that involves moving a red rectangle (player) using the arrow keys. I've gotten the player to move with the arrow keys (arrow keys control velocity, enter key confirms the move), but I need to be able to restrict the amount the player is able to move per turn. I need to make it so that the new velocity/position can only be a maximum of 20 px up/down and 20px left/right (20 px means pressing the arrow key twice).

Currently, the player moves according to the velocity set by the arrow key, but the velocity increases/decreases indefinitely along with the arrow keys. I need it to stop changing once the arrow keys have been pressed a maximum of 2 times in either direction (up/down, left/right).

Here's the code that controls the velocity:

```py
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if p1_turn:
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            p1_velocity_x += 10
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                p1_velocity_x -= 10
```

And here's the code that confirms the change (actually moves the player):

```py
if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
    if p1_turn:
        p1.y += p1_velocity_y
        p1.x += p1_velocity_x
        p1_turn = False
        p2_turn = True
```

As previously mentioned, there should be some mechanism to stop the velocity from going past 20px increase/decrease from the original x velocity and from the original y velocity.

Comment: Instead of using if statements like most of the answers suggest. You could clamp the position between a min and max

Comment: Check the current values of `p1_velocity_x` and `p1_velocity_y` and don't increment it or them when doing so would put them out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pygame

...


#Change those to whatever you want.
maximux_x = 20
minimum_x = 10

#This holds the players velocity on x.
p1_velocity_x = 0

def ChangeVelocity(change):
    global p1_velocity_x

    #cacl new x.
    new_x = p1_velocity_x + change


    if new_x < minimum_x:
        return

    if new_x > maximux_x:
        return

    #Change is inside the restrictions, so apply the change.
    p1_velocity_x += change

...



if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

    if p1_turn:

        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            ChangeVelocity(10)

        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            ChangeVelocity(-10)
```

For better control, you should create sprite objects using classes. An example is shown below:

```py
import pygame


class Vector:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


class Player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.pos      = Vector(0,0)
        self.maxX     = 20
        self.maxY     = 10


    def MoveOnX(self, change):
        global p1_velocity_x

        #cacl new x.
        new_x = self.pos.x + change


        if new_x < self.maxX:
            return


        if new_x > self.maxY:
            return

        #Change is inside the restrictions, so apply the change.
        self.pos.x += change


#Create a new player and spawn him at (5,5)
player = Player()
player.pos.x = 5
player.pos.y = 5


if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

    if p1_turn:

        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            player.MoveOnX(10)

        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            player.MoveOnX(-10)
```

Comment: This works for the most part, but the minimum_x and maximum_x variables need to change with the new x position of the player. Each time it's the player's turn, new restrictions need to be set that limit it to 20 px of movement each side from it's current position.

Comment: Update the minimux_x and maximum_x everytime you change the player's position to be equal to ```minimux_x = player_x - 20``` ```maximum_x = player_x + 20```

Comment: If kindly could you up vote my answer and accept it? Also if you please, give a vote up on my comment here where I answered your other question.

Comment: I have less than 15 reputation, so my vote doesn't show, but I've clicked the vote button.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `if statements`:

```
original_vel_x = 0

if p1_turn:
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        if p1_velocity_x <= original_vel_x + 20:  # I used <= in case it's being increased with floats
            p1_velocity_x += 10
        else: 
            print('Cannot Move')
```

Comment: It has no effect. Where/how would I define original_vel_x?

Comment: It’s a placeholder for whatever your original velocity is

Comment: I have tried something like this before, so you have the right idea, but I have no clue as to why it has no effect.

Comment: Well I haven't defined an 'original velocity.' The only variable I have related to velocity would be the p1_velocity_x.

Comment: So is your original velocity 0?

Comment: That is the initial velocity, yes. That's what I've set p1_velocity_x to at the start of the program.

Comment: so either define an ORIGINAL_VEL constant to 0 or just remove original_velocity_x from my code

Comment: If I set it to 0, it is never updated, meaning the velocity of p1 will never go above 20. I need it to be relative, meaning I need the velocity of p1 to not go 20px above what it was when the right arrow key was pressed, not 20px above 0 every time.

Comment: do not set your velocity to 0. set your *original* velocity to 0. that will never change.

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding what you're saying. Could you post it as code as an answer to the question?

Comment: Do you understand now?